# Surface area of spherical cap by summing up circumferences

Tags: integration, area, spheres

I have seen calculations of the surface area of a spherical cap using a surface of revolution approach. Is it possible to instead cut the spherical cap into slices horizontally (imagine the cap is formed by a horizontal slice of the sphere) and then adding them up (integrating them)?

Comment: Yes - if you remember that the sides are sloping

Comment: Thanks for your comment - are you able to go into more detail please? I thought the fact that the sides were sloping would be taken into account by the formula for the surface area of the slice (something like $\pi sin ^2 x$ where x is the angle between the vertical axis of the sphere and the line from any point on this circumference to the centre of the sphere)

Comment: Try my fuller answer below.  This was originally shown by Archimedes, presumably in [*On the Sphere and Cylinder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sphere_and_Cylinder)

Comment: $\pi \sin^2x$ might be the area of the circular face of a slice--all of which is *inside* the sphere, not on the surface. If you were looking for the volume of the cap that might be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - if you remember that the sides are sloping

Suppose $x$ is the height of a slice from the origin of a sphere radius $r$

Then the circumference of a circle at that height is $2\pi \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ and a slice thickness $\delta x$ is sloping in with sloping distance $\frac{r}{ \sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\delta x +o(\delta x)$ using the almost similar triangles shown below,  so the surface area for that slice is $2\pi r\,\delta x + o(\delta x)$.

It is then a simple integration of $2\pi r$ with respect to $x$ to say that the curved surface area of a spherical cap of height $h$ for a sphere of radius $r$ is $2 \pi r h$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ as an example and calculate the area of the cap over the angle $\theta$. The area is  integrated over a stack of sliced rings with radius $r\sin t$ and width $rdt $, hence area $ds= 2\pi r^2\sin t dt$
$$A = \int_0^{\theta}ds=2\pi r^2 \int_0^{\theta}\sin t dt= 2\pi r^2(1-\cos\theta)
$$